# simple sql question about select in and where

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How can i write a function like this. I have problem with connect where clouses.

```
create or replace function is_valid_value(valuetoCheck in varchar2)
    return varchar2 is 
    v_value valid_values.resourceName%type;
begin
    begin 

            SELECT RESOURCENAME into v_value
            FROM VALID_VALUES
            WHERE VALIDVALUE IN (valuetoCheck)
            where upper(resourceName) =  upper (valuetoCheck);


    exception 
        when no_data_found then
            return 0;
           end;
        return 1;
end is_valid_value ;
```

Comment: `AND`, instead of second `WHERE`.

Comment: use VALIDVALUE=valuetocheck (as IN (one value) is same as = that value), and replace the second where by AND, and why you declare the function to return a VARCHAR2 when it returns 0 or 1 (i.e. numbers)?

Comment: @jarlh it's answer !!

Answer (score 1):

Check this code. Find the comments inline:

```
create or replace function is_valid_value(
    valuetoCheck in varchar2
) return varchar2 
is 
    v_value valid_values.resourceName%type;
begin
    --begin --> there is no need for two 'begin' in this case

            SELECT RESOURCENAME into v_value
            FROM VALID_VALUES
            WHERE VALIDVALUE IN (valuetoCheck)
            AND /* was WHERE, should be change to AND */ upper(resourceName) =  upper (valuetoCheck)
            AND other_value = another_value
            OR this_value = other_value;


    return 1; --> this should be returned before exception

    exception 
        when no_data_found then
            return 0;
           --end; --> there is no need for end since we removed 'begin'

end is_valid_value;
```